# react sortable-js, two types of items and nested items

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sortablejs

I have a problem with react-sortable-js.
I want to create a component that will handle two type of item category and item.

I deal with the following scenario

- Move item J, as a nested item, to section G
- Move nested item I from section G to the same level as item F.
- Move between lists Section G, with all children to the end of the list.

Below is my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sortable-lce48w?file=/src/components/Sortable.tsx

What is wrong and what should I fix?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/302

Comment: @gr33nTHumB It is not helpful for me.